# bounds width are different between iPhone7Plus and iPhone6 version

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I've created Custom UIView and added small delimiter (1point height) inside that UIView. Problem is it's perfectly working on iPhone6 and iPhone7. But `plus` version, it cannot be took 100% of its view width. It needs 40points to fill 100% of its view width. My code is as follow:

```
override func setup() {
    backgroundColor = JBCColor.greySoft
    let border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = JBCColor.darkGrey.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.layer.frame.size.width, height: 2)
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
}
```

Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: I supposed to be that you have UI problem in Layout right?

Comment: precisely, yap.

Comment: You can try using DispatchQueue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve your problem, you need to update layer's frame each time view's frame change. For example, update layer's frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```
class YourView: UIView {

  let border: CALayer = {
    let layer = CALayer()
    layer.backgroundColor = JBCColor.darkGrey.cgColor
    return layer
  }()

  override func setup() {
    backgroundColor = JBCColor.greySoft
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.layer.frame.size.width, height: 2)
  }

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.layer.frame.size.width, height: 2)
  }
}
```

For more detail, you should take a look at [this post](https://marcosantadev.com/calayer-auto-layout-swift/)